# Raspberry PI WebRTC Video Stream via USB Camera on Chromium freezing & blacking out

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, raspberry-pi, webrtc

I have a Raspberry Pi running a Node express server with webRTC.  The Raspberry Pi is connected to a web cam.  I'm able to view the index.html page and see the video stream, but then it randomly freezes or black out completely.  I've tried researching the issue but most solutions refer to changing settings on components that are not part of what I'm using.  Help is sincerely appreciated as I've been banging my head for the past few days.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Stream</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <video playsinline autoplay muted></video>
    <button id="enable-audio">Enable audio</button>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/watch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

broadcast.js

```
// wip 21 January 2022

const peerConnections = {};
const config = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      "urls": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
    },
    // {
    //   "urls": "turn:TURN_IP?transport=tcp",
    //   "username": "TURN_USERNAME",
    //   "credential": "TURN_CREDENTIALS"
    // }
  ]
};

const socket = io.connect(window.location.origin);

socket.on("answer", (id, description) => {
  peerConnections[id].setRemoteDescription(description);
});

socket.on("watcher", id => {
  const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
  peerConnections[id] = peerConnection;

  let stream = videoElement.srcObject;
  stream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream));

  peerConnection.onicecandidate = event => {
    if (event.candidate) {
      socket.emit("candidate", id, event.candidate);
    }
  };

  peerConnection
    .createOffer()
    .then(sdp => peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sdp))
    .then(() => {
      socket.emit("offer", id, peerConnection.localDescription);
    });
});

socket.on("candidate", (id, candidate) => {
  peerConnections[id].addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
});

socket.on("disconnectPeer", id => {
  peerConnections[id].close();
  delete peerConnections[id];
});

window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = () => {
  socket.close();
};

// Get camera and microphone
const videoElement = document.querySelector("video");
const audioSelect = document.querySelector("select#audioSource");
const videoSelect = document.querySelector("select#videoSource");

audioSelect.onchange = getStream;
videoSelect.onchange = getStream;

getStream()
  .then(getDevices)
  .then(gotDevices);

function getDevices() {
  return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
}

function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
  window.deviceInfos = deviceInfos;
  for (const deviceInfo of deviceInfos) {
    const option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
    if (deviceInfo.kind === "audioinput") {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || `Microphone ${audioSelect.length + 1}`;
      audioSelect.appendChild(option);
    } else if (deviceInfo.kind === "videoinput") {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || `Camera ${videoSelect.length + 1}`;
      videoSelect.appendChild(option);
    }
  }
}

function getStream() {
  if (window.stream) {
    window.stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
      track.stop();
    });
  }
  const audioSource = audioSelect.value;
  const videoSource = videoSelect.value;
  const constraints = {
    audio: { deviceId: audioSource ? { exact: audioSource } : undefined },
    video: { deviceId: videoSource ? { exact: videoSource } : undefined }
  };
  return navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(gotStream)
    .catch(handleError);
}

function gotStream(stream) {
  window.stream = stream;
  audioSelect.selectedIndex = [...audioSelect.options].findIndex(
    option => option.text === stream.getAudioTracks()[0].label
  );
  videoSelect.selectedIndex = [...videoSelect.options].findIndex(
    option => option.text === stream.getVideoTracks()[0].label
  );
  videoElement.srcObject = stream;
  socket.emit("broadcaster");
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.error("Error: ", error);
}
```

watch.js

```
let peerConnection;
const config = {
  iceServers: [
      { 
        "urls": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
      },
      // { 
      //   "urls": "turn:TURN_IP?transport=tcp",
      //   "username": "TURN_USERNAME",
      //   "credential": "TURN_CREDENTIALS"
      // }
  ]
};

const socket = io.connect(window.location.origin);
const video = document.querySelector("video");
const enableAudioButton = document.querySelector("#enable-audio");

enableAudioButton.addEventListener("click", enableAudio)

socket.on("offer", (id, description) => {
  peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
  peerConnection
    .setRemoteDescription(description)
    .then(() => peerConnection.createAnswer())
    .then(sdp => peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sdp))
    .then(() => {
      socket.emit("answer", id, peerConnection.localDescription);
    });
  peerConnection.ontrack = event => {
    video.srcObject = event.streams[0];
  };
  peerConnection.onicecandidate = event => {
    if (event.candidate) {
      socket.emit("candidate", id, event.candidate);
    }
  };
});


socket.on("candidate", (id, candidate) => {
  peerConnection
    .addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate))
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
});

socket.on("connect", () => {
  socket.emit("watcher");
});

socket.on("broadcaster", () => {
  socket.emit("watcher");
});

window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = () => {
  socket.close();
  peerConnection.close();
};

function enableAudio() {
  console.log("Enabling audio")
  video.muted = false;
}
```